# Why the first constructor automatically runs without passing argument, even it is not default constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I want to check static variable named 'ccount' using constructor overloading. My code is given below-

```java
public class Circle{
    static int ccount=0; // class variable i.e;static
    public double x,y,r;//instance variable
    public Circle(double x, double y,double r)
    {
        this.x=x;this.y=y;this.r=r;
    }
    public Circle()
    {
        this(0.0,0.0,0.1);
        ccount++;
    }
    public Circle(double r)
    {
        this(0.0,0.0,r);
        ccount++;
    }
    public Circle(Circle c)
    {
        this(c.x,c.y,c.r);
        ccount++;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Circle c1=new Circle();
        Circle c2=new Circle(5.0);
        Circle c3=new Circle(c1);
        System.out.println("c1:" + c1.ccount+ " c2:" + c2.ccount+ " c3:" + c3.ccount);
    }
}
```

output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o9Di.png)

But, When I add ccount++ in my first constructor and my code looks like this:-

```java
public class Circle{
    static int ccount=0; // class variable i.e;static
    public double x,y,r;//instance variable
    public Circle(double x, double y,double r)
    {
        this.x=x;this.y=y;this.r=r;
        ccount++;
    }
    public Circle()
    {
        this(0.0,0.0,0.1);
        ccount++;
    }
    public Circle(double r)
    {
        this(0.0,0.0,r);
        ccount++;
    }
    public Circle(Circle c)
    {
        this(c.x,c.y,c.r);
        ccount++;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Circle c1=new Circle();
        Circle c2=new Circle(5.0);
        Circle c3=new Circle(c1);
        System.out.println("c1:" + c1.ccount+ " c2:" + c2.ccount+ " c3:" + c3.ccount);
    }
}
```

output:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OaeB.png)

I want to know why first constructor automatically runs without passing any argument whenever I create object of class. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: `this(0.0,0.0,0.1);` literally means call the other constructor with the arguments `0.0`, `0.0` and `0.1`.

Comment: It doesn't "automatically" call that constructor. **You explicitly call that constructor in every constructor yourself**.

Comment: Thanks buddy for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called because you call it with `this(0.0,0.0,0.1);`. Try removing that line from the constructor with 0 parameters and you'll see. Whenever you call this() from a constructor, it searches for another constructor that correspond with the number and type of parameters that you are passing in, and then it calls that specific constructor.